# JSON multidimentional array to HTML table Laravel

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

I have a multidimensional JSON array (see array)

```
               {
  "items" : [ {
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "name" : "Pressure Makes Diamonds"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "name" : "Danny Vera"
      } ],
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7rO7Pc5dkC2EIW1OKsCJtQ",
      "name" : "Roller Coaster"
    }
  }, {
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "name" : "Another Day"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "name" : "Racoon"
      } ],
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/64SLdE6sV5g4uQIbVIuRCq",
      "name" : "Love You More"
    }
  }, {
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "name" : "De Echte Vent"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "name" : "Racoon"
      } ],
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/01MCHGtGZHtYVeVUNqgMbC",
      "name" : "De Echte Vent"
    }
  },
```

but I can't seem to succeed in making this a nice HTML table. I tried several things with jQuery (see code beneath), but none of them work.

```
var data = {!! $response !!};

    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    $("#div1").append(tbl);
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        var tr="<tr>";
        var td1="<td>"+data[i]["tracks"]["album"]["name"]+"</td>";

        $("#mytable").append(tr+td1);

    }
```

It is built in Laravel8
Little help would be nice :D

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the JSON in to the question so we can use it to create a working example of your issue. Images of code are largely useless for this reason.

Comment: I edited the post, sorry didn't know

Comment: No problem, thanks for editing. I've added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is because you're looping through `data`, which is the object, not `data.items` which is the array. In addition there is no `tracks` property, it's named `track`.

Once that's corrected the code works:

```js
var data = {"items":[{"track":{"album":{"name":"Pressure Makes Diamonds"},"artists":[{"name":"Danny Vera"}],"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7rO7Pc5dkC2EIW1OKsCJtQ","name":"Roller Coaster"}},{"track":{"album":{"name":"Another Day"},"artists":[{"name":"Racoon"}],"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/64SLdE6sV5g4uQIbVIuRCq","name":"Love You More"}},{"track":{"album":{"name":"De Echte Vent"},"artists":[{"name":"Racoon"}],"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/01MCHGtGZHtYVeVUNqgMbC","name":"De Echte Vent"}}]}

var tbl = $("<table/>").prop("id", "mytable");
$("#div1").append(tbl);

for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
  var tr = "<tr>";
  var td1 = "<td>" + data.items[i]["track"]["album"]["name"] + "</td>";
  $("#mytable").append(tr + td1);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

It's worth noting that this can be simplified using `map()`:

```js
var data = {"items":[{"track":{"album":{"name":"Pressure Makes Diamonds"},"artists":[{"name":"Danny Vera"}],"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7rO7Pc5dkC2EIW1OKsCJtQ","name":"Roller Coaster"}},{"track":{"album":{"name":"Another Day"},"artists":[{"name":"Racoon"}],"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/64SLdE6sV5g4uQIbVIuRCq","name":"Love You More"}},{"track":{"album":{"name":"De Echte Vent"},"artists":[{"name":"Racoon"}],"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/01MCHGtGZHtYVeVUNqgMbC","name":"De Echte Vent"}}]}

let rows = data.items.map(item => `<tr><td>${item.track.album.name}</td></tr>`);
var $tbl = $("<table/>").prop("id", "mytable").html(rows).appendTo('#div1')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I updated the answer to show you a simplified version too.

Comment: Thanks!, now I have to figure out how to make this nice with Bootstrap :d

Comment: Okay last question :). I can't reach the name of the artist? I tried:

`item.track.artists.name`, but I get an "undefined" back in the table?

Comment: `artists` is an array, so you can access them by index (eg.`item.track.artists[0].name` would get the first one), or by looping through to get them all

Comment: right, didn't think about that. the world needs more people you lol. thanks!

Comment: Don't think I'd go that far, but glad it helped at least haha :)

Comment: here I am again, I'm sorry. I tried to edit some of your code and made a Datatable of it, but it doesn't seem to work. This is my current JS:

`<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table_id').DataTable( {
                processing: true,
                data: {!! $response !!},
                columns: [
                    { "track" : "name" },
                    { "track" : "album.name" },
                    { "track" : "artists[0].name" }
                ]
            })
        })
    </script>`

where $response the included json is

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question if you're getting in to Datatables